# How to code a check answer function for every page after submission PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a quizzer for a particular project and I already have all the basic functions being set up.

Basically what it does right now is:

1. Start quiz
2. Attempt multiple choice quiz
3. Go to results page to see your score

Usually this is the usual way of creating a quizzer. However, I would like to allow the answerers to know whether their answer is correct or not on that particular question page itself after he has submitted an answer on that page directly.

But i have no idea how to do it.

I tried searching online for tutorials but there are none I can find that allows the answerer to check the answers on the spot at the page of the question they are answering.

I also tried comparing their selected choice with the correct answer using PHP variables but the computer feedbacks and say that the variable is undefined even though it is defined properly.

Then i shifted the entire process.php file into the question.php file to make sure that the variables on defined in question.php. Yet the computer still feedback to me that the variables `$correct_choice` and `$selected_choice` are not defined.

Below is the code for question.php where the questions are being set FYI:

```
<?php 

include 'database.php'; 
session_start();

$number=(int)$_GET['n'];
$query = "SELECT*FROM questions
           WHERE question_number = $number";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

$question = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$query2 = "SELECT*FROM choices  
           WHERE question_number = $number";
$choices = mysqli_query($con,$query2);

$query="SELECT* FROM questions";
    $results= mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $total=$results->num_rows;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>BTT Quizzer</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
            <h1>BTT Quizzer</h1>
            </div>
        </header>

        <main>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="current">Question <?php echo $question['question_number']; ?> of <?php echo $total; ?></div>
                <p class="question">
                    <?php echo $question['text']?>
                </p>
                <form method="post" action="">
                    <ul class="choices">
                        <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($choices)): ?>
                        <li><input name="choice" type="radio" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"/><?php echo $row['text']?></li>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                    </ul>
                    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="number" value="<?php echo $number; ?>"/>
                </form>

                <div class="feedback">
                    <?php if($correct_choice == $selected_choice){
                       echo "Thats Correct!";
                      }
                    ?>
                </div>

                <div class="feedback2">
                    <?php if($correct_choice != $selected_choice){
                       echo "Thats Wrong!";
                      }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>

        <footer>
            <div class="container">
                Copyright &copy;2014,BTT Quizzer
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is the code for process.php FYI:

```
include 'database.php';
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['score'])){
        $_SESSION['score'] = 0;
    }

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $number=$_POST['number'];
    $selected_choice = $_POST['choice'];
    $next=$number+1;

    $query="SELECT*FROM questions";
    $results= mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $total=$results->num_rows;

    $query = "SELECT*FROM`choices` WHERE question_number = $number AND is_correct=1";
    $results= mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $row=$results->fetch_assoc();
    $correct_choice=$row['id'];

    if($correct_choice == $selected_choice){
        $_SESSION['score']++;
    }

    if($number == $total){
        header("Location: final.php");
        exit();
    } else {
        header("Location: question.php?n=".$next);
    }
}
```

Comment: The score will never be reset to 0. The score can double-count the same answer. Also setting the Location header looks funny. And this code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. And Questions should probably belong to a Quiz. And not defined is not defined.. the two PHP programs are not magically 'linked'. Assigning the correct_choice/selected_choice in one does not necessarily effect the other.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

Use a super global $_SESSION to get the variables from process.php and echo it into question.php with conditionals.